# Trying to search through a list of months/years (excel vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to try and find all instances of a month + " Sales " + year, and then delete the row. However, I get a mismatch error. I don't think my .Find function can take an argument of a list. I tried using a loop WITHIN my loop to cycle through all the variables in my list, but still getting a mismatch error. Any ideas on how I can sort this out? Thanks:

```
'Add months and years for other possibilities
Dim mymonth() As String
Dim myyear() As String
mymonth = Split("September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August", ",")
myyear = Split("2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020", ",")

'now check
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1", ActiveSheet.Range("C65536").End(xlUp))
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(mymonth + " Sales " + myyear, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Bonus if you can figure out a better way to find any year in yyyy format instead of listing them out manually. I'm sure I could use the date function to achieve this but I'm having a hard enough time getting this to take just a plain list...

Comment: `Set c = SrchRng.Find(mymonth & " Sales " & myyear, LookIn:=xlValues)`. I think you want the `&` instead of `+`.  Also, don't you need to define which `myMonth` and `myYear` you want to search each time? After the split, it's an array.  But, what are you trying to do? Just Delete a row when ...a certain month/year combo is found?

Comment: I tried "&" as well, same error. I'm trying to delete all occurrences, for example, April Sales 2014, October Sales 2016, November Sales 2018, etc. It switches all the time. I am trying to define "mymonth" as ANY month, so should I be defining it as a string? A variant? I tried a couple different combos to no avail

Comment: To be clear - you want to delete rows with `January Sales 2014`, `February Sales 2014`, ..., `December Sales 2014`, then do the same loop of all 12 months with 2015, 2016, ..., 2020?

Comment: If you're deleting *every* month within those years, why not just look for those years?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, that's right. And tigeravatar, I need it to be specifically Month + Sales + Year, because sometimes we might have something that ends in "Sales 2017" that I might not want to delete.

Comment: fwiw, the correct string concatenation operator in VBA is an ampersand (e.g. `&`) not a plus sign (e.g. `+`) but in a pinch, a plus sign *can* be used when there is no ambiguity with a strictly mathematical operation. It is still not considered 'best practice'.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. I do typically use the "&", this was a bad example of my code.

Comment: Final question - I assume you have cells with dates *not* in your list above? I.e. `January Sales 1993`, ..., `September Sales 2011`, etc?

Comment: If had an actual date in a column, you could use a custom number format mask of `mmmm \S\al\e\s yyyy` to achieve January Sales 2014. After that, finding a year's worth of dates is easy.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't have older dates, however I'd like to be able to account for any future dates (beyond 2020, etc.)

Comment: @Jeeped The cells aren't formatted to anything like a date, it's just strings of text, so I'm not sure if that would work? Not sure if I'm following...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim aYears() As Variant
    Dim aMonths() As Variant
    Dim vYear As Variant
    Dim vMonth As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sFirst As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rSearch = ws.Columns("C").EntireColumn
    aMonths = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    aYears = Array(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)

    For Each vYear In aYears
        For Each vMonth In aMonths
            sTemp = vMonth & " Sales " & vYear
            Set rFound = Nothing
            Set rFound = rSearch.Find(sTemp, rSearch.Cells(rSearch.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart, , xlNext, False)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                sFirst = rFound.Address
                If rDel Is Nothing Then Set rDel = rFound Else Set rDel = Union(rDel, rFound)
                Do
                    Set rDel = Union(rDel, rFound)
                    Set rFound = rSearch.FindNext(rFound)
                Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
            End If
        Next vMonth
    Next vYear

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for all your work - I was hoping the answer wouldn't be as difficult as it looks... So using arrays, you looped through all of the variables in aMonths and aYears?

Comment: Thanks. I tried using a loop before, but I didn't include the ranges like you did. Lesson learned

Answer (score 2):

Bulk Autofilter operations are typically much faster then looping through individual Find operations.

```
Dim iMonth As Long, iYear As Long, sSales As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Intersect(.Columns("C"), .UsedRange)
        For iYear = 2014 To 2020
            For iMonth = 1 To 12
                sSales = Format(DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, 1), "mmmm \S\a\l\e\s yyyy")
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=sSales
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        .EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End With
            Next iMonth
        Next iYear
    End With
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for this solution... I'll have to test both and see if there are any major differences with speed. One thing I have never liked about Autofilter solutions, though, is that if any of my sheet is protected/locked, it returns an error. Then I have to add extra lines of code to unprotect with my password, and I never like having my password in my code... Have you seen this problem before?

Comment: It is going to depend on how many multiple matches you have. If there are typically one (or none) of the majority of month/date combinations then any difference will be small. If speed is an issue, disabling screenupdating, events and calculation will make more of a difference.

Comment: Right right. I already have all of those disabled and turning back on at the end, but if this project of mine grows and I have to add other scenarios to the code/the amount of rows I'm checking grows then I'll definitely be watching for speed. T